# Reevaluate onComplete JSF - primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to update a window's content by clicking on a primefaces commandlink:

```
<p:commandLink oncomplete="if( #{documentController.documentAlreadyOpenedInExternalWindow} ) window.open('previewDocument.xhtml?documentId=#{documentController.documentId(task)}', 'new');"
```

but the condition check never seems to be tested again?

```
<p:commandLink oncomplete="if( true ) window.open('previewDocument.xhtml?documentId=#{documentController.documentId(task)}', 'new');"
```

the above statement will ofcourse open the window with every click..

How could I solve this?

Primefaces 5.2

Comment: by updating the commandLink itself...

Comment: @Kukeltje tried that but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working"... What **does** happen? What does the response look like? What did you actually do?

Comment: @Kukeltje I've fixed it and I'll post the solution later today. But what happened: I only want to 'update' (open) the screen if it has already been opened (see boolean condition). The boolean never resulted to true even though it was true in the backend because the link didn't get updated because the initial opening happend in a ajax=false commandLink with a target="new". As I said, I'll post my solution later today.

Answer (score -1):

what i understood question is you are trying to update a content of window if it is already open else open new window you can use conditional operator and if your field `documentAlreadyOpenedInExternalWindowis` is boolean then you can use like this

```
    <p:commandLink oncomplete="
        #{documentController.documentAlreadyOpenedInExternalWindow?alert('succeed');
    :window.open('previewDocument.xhtml?documentId=#{documentController.documentId(task)}', 'new')" 
update="yourElement/Form ID"/>
```

Comment: That's what's placed in my question and doesn't work. The onComplete gets evaluated at the render of my page and not anymore after the completion of the action.

Comment: Is the controller is in view scoped?  and the page from where you are opening and the page which you have opened is referring to same controller  and what's the scope of those controllers try to put a debug point in constructor and setter of the field i think your field is reinitializing either once you are navigating to other window or when you are clicking what's the value of `documentAlreadyOpenedInExternalWindow` when you are clicking.